# A question about the permissiones of files generated after the APK installation

Tags: android, installation, directory, permissions, apk

I know that some directories(e.g. /data/data/{package}/lib) will be generated after APK installation.I want to know whether the permissions(e.g.-rwxr-xr-x) of these directories and files in them can be set at the code level before APK installation？Or is the permission of the files generated during installation granted by the Android system during installation and the permissions cannot be set in advance？How can I do to implement it if the permissions of the generated file can be set in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files in data/data/package/ are always private to your application.  No other process can read or write them (except the system, of course).  And there's no way to override those permissions at install time.  You probably could at runtime, but I'm not sure why you'd want to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was studying the security test of Android APK and encountered such problems. Can I set the permissions of these generated private directories and files in the code before packaging APK so that it will generate files with corresponding permissions under these directories during installation?

Comment: No, because these are created by the Android system, not your apk.  If you need to poke around in those directories, I suggest rooting the device.  That would allow you to look at the files.